# How to declare a C function with an undetermined return type?

Tags: objective-c, c, function, return-type

Can I declare a C function with an undetermined return type (without C compiler warning)? The return type could be `int`, `float`, `double`, `void *`,  etc.

```
undetermined_return_type miscellaneousFunction(undetermined_return_type inputValue);
```

And you can use this function in other functions to return a value (although that could be a run time error):

```
BOOL isHappy(int feel){
    return miscellaneousFunction(feel);
};

float percentage(float sales){
    return miscellaneousFunction(sales);
};
```

---

**What I'm looking for:**

To declare and to implement a C function (or Obj-C method) with an undefined-return-type could be useful for aspect-oriented programming.

If I could intercept Obj-C messages in another function in run time, I might return the value of that message to the original receiver or not with doing something else action. For example:

```
- (unknown_return_type) interceptMessage:(unknown_return_type retValOfMessage){
    // I may print the value here
    // No idea how to print the retValOfMessage (I mark the code with %???)
    print ("The message has been intercepted, and the return value of the message is %???", retValOfMessage);

    // Or do something you want (e.g. lock/unlock, database open/close, and so on).
    // And you might modify the retValOfMessage before returning.
    return retValOfMessage;
}
```

So I can intercept the original message with a little addition:

```
// Original Method
- (int) isHappy{
    return [self calculateHowHappyNow];
}

// With Interception
- (int) isHappy{
    // This would print the information on the console.
    return [self interceptMessage:[self calculateHowHappyNow]];
}
```

Comment: This is interesting ask. I don't think it can be achieved in `C`. You may want to use a `void *` to achieve it in a not-as-clean-as-you-asked-above manner.

Comment: Why not use a `union`? Also, what is the purpose of this?

Comment: Can `union` include all kinds of return type, even object types in Objective-C and C++?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `void *` type.

Then for example:

```
float percentage(float sales){
    return *(float *) miscellaneousFunction(sales);
}
```

Be sure not to return a pointer to a object with automatic storage duration.

Comment: Wouldn't you also have to pass the parameter as void* as there is no function overloading in C? This would make it even more ugly. Glad there are templates in C++ :)

Comment: @typ1232 It answers OP question but I actually find this ugly in C and would try my best to avoid it in my own programs.

Comment: What if my `miscellaneousFunction` returns another function which also returns an undefined return type? Could you make an example about how to implement this `miscellaneousFunction`?

Answer (score 1):

You may use the preprocessor.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define FUNC(return_type, name, arg)        \
return_type name(return_type arg)           \
{                                           \
    return miscellaneousFunction(arg);      \
}

FUNC(float, undefined_return_func, arg)

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("\n %f \n", undefined_return_func(3.14159));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I need this function to return values of undefined return types dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

May be a `union` as suggested by [thejh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18804240/how-to-declare-a-c-function-with-an-undetermined-return-type#comment27731903_18804240)

```
typedef struct 
{
  enum {
      INT,
      FLOAT,  
      DOUBLE
  } ret_type;
  union
    {
       double d;
       float f;
       int i; 
    } ret_val;
} any_type;

any_type miscellaneousFunction(any_type inputValue) {/*return inputValue;*/}

any_type isHappy(any_type feel){
    return miscellaneousFunction(feel);
}

any_type percentage(any_type sales){
    return miscellaneousFunction(sales);
}
```

Here with `ret_type` you can know data type of return value and `ret_type.` `i,f,d` can give you corresponding value.

All elements will use same memory space and only one should be accessed.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but I need to declare the `isHappy()` and `percentage ()` method with the explicit return types.

Answer (score 0):

Straight C doesn't support dynamically-typed variables (variants) since it is statically typed, but there might be some libraries that do what you want.